# Gorm WHERE clause not working on Preload data

Tags: go, go-gorm

This query here below works, where the `where` clause works becuase it's using values from `ResourceUsage` struct, but I would love to be able to do something like this, where the `where` clause is using value from the `ResourceMetadata` struct.

> db.Preload("ResourceMetadata").Where("resource_type = ?", resourceType).Where("timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?", start, end).Limit(10).Find(&resourceUsage)

But it throws exception:

> 2019-12-03 11:06:12]  Error 1054: Unknown column 'resource_type' in 'where clause'

**Code:**

```
// ResourceUsage describes the storage model for resource-usage
type ResourceUsage struct {
    ID               int64             `json:"-"`
    DetailsID        int64             `json:"details_id"`
    ResourceMetadata *ResourceMetadata `gorm:"foreignkey:DetailsID;association_foreignkey:ID"`
    MeasuredType     string            `json:"measured_type"`
    Quantity         float64           `json:"quantity"`
    Timestamp        int64             `json:"timestamp"`
}

// ResourceMetadata describes the storage model for resource-usage
type ResourceMetadata struct {
    ID                  int64  `json:"-"`
    ResourceUUID        string `json:"resource_uuid"`
    ResourceName        string `json:"resource_name"`
    ResourceDisplayName string `json:"resource_display_name"`
    ResourceType        string `json:"resource_type"`
}

db.Preload("ResourceMetadata").Where("timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?", start, end).Limit(10).Find(&resourceUsage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a JOIN?

```golang
    resourceUsages := []ResourceUsage{}
    if err := db.Joins("JOIN resource_metadata ON resource_metadata.id=details_id").
        Where("resource_metadata.resource_type = ? AND timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?", resourceType, start, end).
        Preload("ResourceMetadata").Limit(10).
        Find(&resourceUsages).Error; err != nil {
        // ... handle error ...
    }
```